# How to do remote notification on Windows

Tags: windows, notifications

I'd like to send notification to users on some condition, from Linux to Windows.

Explanation: On Linux we are monitoring the temperature of all rooms (every 5 minutes). If the temperature is too high or too low, some action should be done - turn on heater or cooler. Now I'm sending emails, but if user doesn't run a mail client, he doesn't receive the message.

The best is to show modal form on user screen - so he have to make some action to close the window (he couldn't said later, that he hasn't seen it).

I thought about Toast popups but according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465391.aspx):

> Don't use toast notifications to notify the user of critical
>   information. Instead, to ensure that critical alerts are seen, notify
>   users within your app using a flyout, dialog, app bar, or other inline
>   element.

Any ideas?